# Python, create a list with cusom name

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something like:

```
a = input("Enter the name of your list")
"{n}".format(n = a) = []
```

Which is obviously doesn't work. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: *Don't do this*. Instead, use a *container*, like a `list` or a `dict`

Answer (score 4):

One way to have a variable with a user-supplied name is to create that variable as an item within a dictionary.

```
the_dict = {}
a = input("Enter the name of your list")
the_dict[a] = []
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `exec` and `eval`:

```
a = input("Enter the name of your list")
exec(str(a)+"=[]")
print(eval(a))
```

This does exactly what you want, while this is not recommended, for better solution please refer to John's answer.

Comment: This does work, but there are very good reasons not to do it unless you know exactly what you're doing.  Definitely not recommended for beginners.

Comment: @JohnGordon Just edited before I saw your comment